# Why does the Item count for a ListView Return Null if their is 1 item in the ListView ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I don't get this issue.  If I have a ListView and it is databound to a datatable with 1 item in the listview, why does the Item Count = 0 when I try to access a control in the ListView using the ListView.Item[0].FindControl(".....") method?

Here is sample code from the msdn page on the ListView Control.  Imagine the SqlDataSource1 returns 1 row from the database so it gets inserted into the ItemTemplate, I would think that Item[0] would correspond to that Item, but it does not?

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" runat="server" >
    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server>
    <td runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
      Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on: in which sequence/phase of the page life-cycle did you call the `FindControl` method?

Comment: Please could you include some source?

Comment: After the page has been loaded and the ListView has been databound.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling FindControl.

Comment: I could be calling it anywhere. For Example, I have a method called IsAdmin() which is supposed to get return whether a User is an Admin and if they are not, I want to get the hide an asp.net LinkButton which is located in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Are you assigning your datasource programmatically? See this thread:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1086562/1619347.aspx as it might apply to listviews as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your ListView isn't actually finished databinding at the spot your code is running.

Try wiring a method to the ListView's ItemDataBound event.  This will fire after each item in the data source has been processed by the ListView.  In that method you can use FindControls to find controls and update their state.

Example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewProducts" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductsDataSource"
OnItemDataBound="ListViewProducts_ItemDataBound" >
... ItemTemplate defines a link button called LinkButtonDoAdminStuff ...


protected void ListViewProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var myLinkButton = e.Item.FindControl("LinkButtonDoAdminStuff") as LinkButton;
    if (myLinkButton != null)
        myLinkButton.Visible = IsAdmin();
}
```